# Spring Boot Jdbc Flyway Version File Name "V1__script.sql" not working instead renaming file with "V1_file.sql" is working

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, flyway

I have tried flyway(5.2.3) with Spring boot(2.1.0-Release) for MySQL (5.7) without JPA, 
When I tried to run the Spring boot project the flyway version script file with the name **"V1__script.sql"** **is only creating one table and it throws exception SQL Syntax error for the second table** with local MySQL version.
If I have created the multiple files with **V1__script.sql, V2__script.sql, V3__script.sql** by having a single table script in it that is also working fine.

Version details :

- Flyway: 5.2.3
- Spring Boot: 2.1.0-Release
- MySQL: 5.7

But when I renamed the file from "V1__file.sql" that works fine without any error.

Is there anything that I missed in the configuration. Is Flyway is not supporting "script" word in script file name?

Thank you.

Comment: How does the content of the first version of V1 look like and what error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple statements are allowed in the sql script used by FlyWay. However it should be correct sql statements. Make sure you finished the lines with an semicolon(;)

The best test for a correct file is running it with something else. If you can import the file using `mysql options table < V1__file.sql` then FlyWay should work also.

If you rename the file to `V1_file.sql` it will be ignored by FlyWay.

Comment: But the same script is working with V1__file.sql but if I rename it to V1__script.sql then it will throw exception SQL syntax error.

Comment: If V1__file.sql and V1__script.sql are both running at the same time you will get an exception about duplicate version 1. You are saying an SQL syntax error, so i assume you are running it against an empty database with only one file. If the file has the same content an both files have the extension .sql then it does not make sense. The part you change is only the description part. https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#naming

Comment: Thank you Martin for your reply, 
I'm not using two files at a time, I either use V1__file.sql or V1__script.sql. But the problem which I'm facing with V1__script.sql and it is working fine with V1__file.sql(Even if exact same content).

Comment: That is strange I have tried it in my project and had no problems. Can't help you, sorry